# Insert spaces and values in list python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a file with numbers from 0 to 99, but each one has to be an a line of the txt.

```
lista=[]
for i in range (100):
    a=str(i)
    lista.append(a)
print lista    

arch = open('numeros.txt', 'w')
for i in range (100):
    linea = lista[i]
    arch.write(linea)
arch.close()
```

The result in the file is 0123...
but i need like:

```
0

1

2

3

.
.
.
```

Is there any way to insert a jumpspace on each line?

Answer (score 1):

`file.write()` does not automatically add newlines to your file. You have to add them manually.

Example -

```
arch = open('numeros.txt', 'w')
for i in range (100):
    linea = lista[i]
    arch.write("{}\n".format(linea))

arch.close()
```

If you want two newlines , do - `'{}\n\n'.format(linea)` .

Also, you do not need to iterate over the range and then take element from each, index, instead you can just iterate over the list -

```
for i in lista:
    arch.write("{}\n".format(i))
arch.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace `arch.write(linea)` with: `` arch.write(`linea` + "\n") ``.

That will insert a new-line character after each number.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can use, you don't need to write two separate loops.

```
arch = open('numeros.txt', 'w')
for i in range(100):
    arch.write(str(i) + '\n')
arch.close()
```